# How to Copy Range of Filtered Data and Paste it to new work sheet in Excel VBA (without Using Clipboard)

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, macros, microsoft-excel-2016

I want to Copy ColumnA and B to New sheet Range A and B (Source Sheet Filter Applied in ColumnH)

This code is Recorded one, When i use this Random Error comes. Because i have 5 submacro and When i call these sub macro its not run correctly. But individual Macro run perfectly.

So i need to Copy without use of Clipboard like this method. Its not use when filter applied condition

```
Sheets("GROUP1").Range("A:B").Value = Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A:B").Value
```

Recorded Macro

```
Sub Copypaste()
'Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Sheets("GROUP1").Select

    Cells.Select
    Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Range("A1:H1").Select
    Range("H1").Activate
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A:$H").AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:="K-True", Operator:=xlFilterValues
    Columns("A:B").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy

       DoEvents
    Sheets("Sheet3").Select
    Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: why you can't use copy? Does your macros use the clipboard?

Comment: i think overload . because some time automatically close it self without error. So i need to transfer data without copy

Comment: @mate juhasz When i use copy process it must use clipboard that is slow down the process and some times not responding , Due to repeated load for clipboard at few seconds.

Comment: Seems to be an xy problem, other methods with vba would be even slower

Comment: @mate juhasz atleast how copy paste these datas without any error . because i am using 5sub macro each one have 4 copy paste process.

Comment: i dont know xy problem ,what are the other method copy paste when filter mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is loop through the source sheet checking by `Cell.RowHeight > 0` then setting `DestinationCell.Value = SourceCell.Value`. Ex.:

```
Sub Copypaste()
    Dim lRow As Long, lLastRow As Long, LRowCount As Long

    Sheets("GROUP1").Select

    Cells.Select
    Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Range("A1:H1").Select
    Range("H1").Activate
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A:$H").AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:="K-True", Operator:=xlFilterValues        
    lRowCount = 1
    lLastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells.SpeciallCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

    For lRow = 1 to lLastRow

        If ActiveSheet.Range(lRow).RowHeight > 0 Then
            Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A" & lRowCount & ":B" & lRowCount).Value = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & lRowCount & ":B" & lRowCount).Value
            lRowCount = lRowCount + 1
        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

P.S.: If you have any issues, please let me know.